# Configuring a devcontainer for a Poetry-managed Python project and VS Code plugins

Tags: python, python-poetry, codespaces

I've having a surprisingly rough time today configuring a GitHub Codespace to create an environment for developing a Poetry-managed Python library compatible with the VS Code Python plugin.

The main problem I've wrestled with: Poetry can be configured to install a virtual environment into a local `.venv` directory. The VS Code Python plugin seems to expect the virtual environment to live in `.env`. If I try `"customizations": { "vscode": { "settings": { "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv" }}}`, I see the amended setting appear in the `Remote [Codespaces]` tab, but the Python plugin seems to ignore it.

Can anyone suggest a complete `.devcontainer.json` that wires a Codespace with the VS Code Python plugin for development of a Poetry-managed Python library?